# Java with If statement and random numbers

Tags: java, if-statement, random

i'm a beginners in Java and i need help for this block:

The problem i have here is, when the number is less than 6 in the first "if" statement, it dont get add to the score at the end.
I know the wrong thing i'm doing is in the second "if" statement, i initialize the score to 0, but how i can do so both of the "if" statement can be added to the score when it's higher than 6 and NOT added when it's less than 6? When the random number is less than 6, it shouldn't be added to the score. I don't know if i'm explaning well, but thank you for  your time!

```
int shot;
    int score = 0;
    shot = rand.nextInt(11);
    score += shot;

    if (shot > 6) {

        System.out.print("\nSHOT " + a + ".... Challenger shoots: " + shot);

        }
        else { 
            score = 0;
            System.out.print("\nSHOT " + a + ".... Challenger shoots: " +  "You missed the board!");
        }

    shot = rand.nextInt(11);
    score += shot;
    if (shot > 6) {
    System.out.print("\nSHOT " + (++a) + ".... Challenger shoots " + shot);
    }
    else {
        score = 0;
        System.out.print("\nSHOT " + (++a) + ".... Challenger shoots: " +  "You missed the board!");

    }

    System.out.print("\nCHALLENGER SCORE: " + score);
```

Comment: it is not two players, it is a player who shoots an arrow twice, and the result is calculated according to where the arrow landed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as

```
int score = 0;
int shot;

System.out.println("Shot#1:"); 
shot = rand.nextInt(11);
if (shot > 6) {
    score += shot;
    System.out.print("\nSHOT " + a + ".... Challenger shoots: " + shot);
} else {
    System.out.print("\nSHOT " + a + ".... Challenger shoots: You missed the board!");
}

System.out.println("Shot#2:"); 
shot = rand.nextInt(11);
if (shot > 6) {
    score += shot;
    System.out.print("\nSHOT " + (++a) + ".... Challenger shoots: " + shot);
} else {
    System.out.print("\nSHOT " + (++a) + ".... Challenger shoots: You missed the board!");
}

System.out.print("\nCHALLENGER SCORE: " + score);
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, but this code is for only one shots of arrow right?

Comment: I think score = 0; is wrong here, you shouldn't reset the score.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope - I also think so now. The question is not clear. Let's wait for OP's feedback.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thank you so much Sir for your help and your time, it worked !

Answer (score -1):

from what you have explained .i understood that .,

if the random numbers for both cases are greater than 6 you need it to be added and store to a variable score else if any of them are below 6 then nothing should be added.

if so ., i suggest .

```java
    int shot;
    int score = 0;
    shot = rand.nextInt(11);

    if (shot > 6) {
        score += shot; // if the random number greater than 6 add it to score
        System.out.print("\nSHOT " + a + ".... Challenger shoots: " + shot);

        }
        else { 
           // score = 0; - line not required its already zero
            System.out.print("\nSHOT " + a + ".... Challenger shoots: " +  "You missed the board!");
        }

    shot = rand.nextInt(11);


    if (shot > 6) {
    score += shot;    // if the random number greater than 6 add it to score
    System.out.print("\nSHOT " + (++a) + ".... Challenger shoots " + shot);
    }
    else {
        // score = 0; - comment this line
        System.out.print("\nSHOT " + (++a) + ".... Challenger shoots: " +  "You missed the board!");

    }

    System.out.print("\nCHALLENGER SCORE: " + score);
```

EDIT 1 : I have edited the above code try it out.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your time, i tried your code and same problem. that's the output: 
SHOT 1.... Challenger shoots: 9
SHOT 2.... Challenger shoots: You missed the board!
CHALLENGER SCORE: 0

Comment: The score should be 9 but it's 0 and that's my problem

Comment: which means if any of the random number is greater than 6 you need to add it to the score.so it is not recommended to reset the score.